# How to populate href value from src value of an image?

Tags: javascript

I know this is super simple, but I can't work it out (I'm a designer).

I want to simply populate the href attribute value of the `<a>` tag, with the value of the src attribute of the `<img>` tag. So the image links to itself basically.

the image src will be updated through a super simple CMS and I want the link to dynamically update, instead of the user having to update the URL also.

I tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
<a rel="lightbox[job1]" href="()document.getElementById("gal1_img1").src">
<img id="gal1_img1" src="images/gallery/job1/image-1.jpg">`enter code here`
</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

You cannot inline JavaScript inside attributes the way you have currently. You can add a script to the page to do this:

```
<a id="link" rel="lightbox[job1]" href="#">
<img id="gal1_img1" src="images/gallery/job1/image-1.jpg">`enter code here`
</a>

<script>
document.getElementById("link").href = document.getElementById("gal1_img1").src;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, how would I also make this work for multiple images, each with their own link? So basically the element "link" is always equal to the value of the img src inside that tag.

Answer (score 5):

try this as your `<a>`'s href:

```
href="javascript:window.location=this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;"
```

Assuming there's only ever one image inside these `<a>` tags, this should work for anyone who's NOT running with javascript disabled.

Comment: thanks for your response Marc B... I don't think it likes Javascript inline in the href attribute though.... I had the same problem? I know it can work somehow though??

Comment: I thought there was a conflict with the JScript I'm using with the light box, as it wont work. but even when I remove links to those JS files, I get nothing? what's the '[0]' in reference to?

Comment: @drewD83: getelementsbytagname returns a nodelist (basically an array) of matching nodes, so the [0] just pulls the first matching element off the list, which would be the first (and hopefully only) img inside your a.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 var att = $('#gal1_img1').attr('src');
 $("a[rel*='lightbox[job1]']").attr('href',att);
```